# why virtual ports in linux don't change behavior when i change terminal attributes?

Tags: linux, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

i try to test serial communication using virtual-serial-ports in linux.
these are the steps i do:

1. create the virtual ports:
   `socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 &`
   that allocate `/dev/pts/1` and `/dev/pts/2`
2. open connections from both sides and set different baudrates:

```
// from thread 1:
int fd1 = open("/dev/pts/1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
int baudrate = B115200;
struct termios newtio;
bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
newtio.c_cflag = baudrate | CRTSCTS | CLOCAL | CREAD;
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);

// from thread 2:
int fd2 = open("/dev/pts/2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
int baudrate = B9600;
struct termios newtio;
bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
newtio.c_cflag = baudrate | CRTSCTS | CLOCAL | CREAD;
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);

// notice that the baudrate is configured different
```

3. start to communicate between them:

```
// from thread 1:
write(fd1, "test\n", 5);

// from thread 2:
read(fd2, buffer, MAX_RECEIVED_LEN);
```

and for some reason, the communication succeed although the baudrate is not the same. and even if i change any other attribute i still work.
why doesn't it fail? is the virtual port doesn't simulate real serial communication?

Comment: Your termios initialization is improper. See http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237 .   *"why doesn't it fail?"* -- Pseudo terminal devices do not use/perform serialization, so the baudrate is not salient.  *"is the virtual port doesn't simulate real serial communication?"* -- `/dev/pty/1` and `/dev/pty/2` are a pair of pseudo-terminal devices, and not *"virtual serial ports"*.  *"why virtual ports in linux don't change behavior when i change terminal attributes?"* -- You only changed just one attribute, and then make a blanket conclusion for everything?

Comment: thank you for the answer. it was much of a help